# Cakephp4 internationalization locale is changed but translated text is not showing

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, multilingual, cakephp-4.x

I have cakephp4.2 project want to implement multilanguage feature followed [cakephp documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

```
debug(I18n::getLocale()); exit; **//----this returns 'ar_AE' ----//**
```

above line shows that cuurent locale is `ar_AE` but still `__('hello world')` is not translated to arabic

I have set `App.defaultLocale` equal to `ar_AE` in `config/app.php`
I also have translation files as below
`myproject\resources\Locale\ar_AE\Default.po`
`myproject\resources\Locale\ar_AE\Default.mo`

`myproject\resources\Locale\en_US\Default.po`
`myproject\resources\Locale\en_US\Default.mo`

I also wrote below in `AppController`

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event){       
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $Session = $this->request->getSession(); 
    if($Session->check('Config.language')){
        I18n::setLocale($Session->read('Config.language'));
    }else{
        $Session->write('Config.language','ar_AE');
    }
    //debug(I18n::getLocale()); exit; **//----this returns 'ar_AE' ----//**
}
```

dont know what is missing or I am doing any mistake.

`default.po` few top lines

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2021-06-08 15:30+0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2021-06-08 16:17+0400\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: ar_AE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 3.0\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ../../../templates\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=6; plural=(n==0 ? 0 : n==1 ? 1 : n==2 ? 2 : n%100>=3 "
"&& n%100<=10 ? 3 : n%100>=11 && n%100<=99 ? 4 : 5);\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: __\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: Admin/Clients/view.php:28 Admin/Experiences/view.php:22 Clients/view.php:26
msgid "Company"
msgstr "الشركة"

#: Admin/Clients/view.php:34 Clients/view.php:30
msgid "Designation"
msgstr "مُعرف المسمى الوظيفي"

#: layout/error.php:38
#, fuzzy
msgid "Back"
msgstr "وية الامارتية – الجهة الخلفية"
```

Comment: For starters the filenames are ment to be lowercase. Also we don't know what's actually inside of your `.po` and `.mo` files, the problem might be located there. Finally make sure to always clear your cache (`tmp/cache/persistent`) after making changes to translations.

Comment: Dear @ndm I have made `po` and `mo` file lowecased, also removed all files from tmp/cache/presistent. still not showing arabic text. I have edited question and added default.po file content

Comment: I see... one additional thing I've overlooked in your paths, it needs to be `locales`, not `Locale`!

Comment: yes, `locales` worked